# How to easily extend Jetpack Compose components?

Tags: kotlin, tabs, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, extend

I want to make a custom implementation of `ScrollableTabRow` which allows for a composable element to be displayed 'sticky'ly at the right end of the tab row. But I can't figure out a simple way to extend the functionalities of the default implementation.

Firstly, `ScrollableTabRow` is not a class, so I can't really 'extend' it. It is a function, so I will have to duplicate it (and rename it to, say, `StickyTabRow`), and then change the logic wherever and however I see fit. However, the problem with this is that the default implementation of `ScrollableTabRow` uses several private and internal variables, singleton objects and functions that I cannot access in my own file. So I will need to copy all of these dependencies into `StickyTabRow`, and then the dependencies of these dependencies, and so on.

Surely implementing a custom Composable component isn't this difficult? What am I missing here?

Comment: You are right, Composables are not classes so they cannot be extended. They are designed to be, well, composed. It's in the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Surely implementing a custom Composable component isn't this
> difficult? What am I missing here?

Most of the time a Composable that contains core Composable and your  own logic or or parameter, or combining Modifiers are enough to accomplish your requirements.

Such as creating a Scoped Composable here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/74002236/5457853

or a shake Modifier

[Android Compose create shake animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73630460/android-compose-create-shake-animation)

can be done adding some code instead of copy-pasting whole Rows or Modifier codes.

But, there are cases hat you need to write Composables or Modifiers by copy-pasting source code to update very small part because some params are not exposed to developers.

For instance, to change minimum size a ScrollableTabRow row can have you need to copy paste whole source code to just change so your tabs can have minimum size lower than 90.dp.

```
private val ScrollableTabRowMinimumTabWidth = 90.dp
```

as here.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76533630/5457853

Or when you need an Image composable that returns bounds of drawable area other than black lines you need to rewrite it from scratch.

https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Compose-Image

Or a Slider that you can add custom thumb, it was re-written for Material3 but in M2 version it's not available. So you need to rewrite it from scratch.

Also there is no click, transform drag modifier that lets you not consume or change propagation direction. So in such a case you need to rewrite source code as here. Transform gestures also don't return when gestures started or ended.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76021552/5457853

or here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70847531/5457853

There can be many examples you might need to copy-paste a Composable or a Modifier but compared the situations you can use default composables or Modifiers these are not that a lot.

If it's some parameter that you need that is not exposed and there is no other way to change it via Constraints, size Modifier, other Modifiers or wrapping it inside another Composable your option is to copy-paste source code and change where it needs changes.

But good thing is most of the Composable components are pretty straightforwards, except LazyLists, and easy to do modification after copy-pasting.

Comment: Well that's a bummer. Thanks for the info anyway!

Comment: Even in these cases that you need to copy-paste source it let's you learn a lot. I inspected almost every standard Composable source code and helps a lot how you should write your Composables and you learn  if a Composable doesn't workin some case why a Composable doesn't work easily. LazyList codes are complicated though. Button, Image, Slider, Switch/CheckBox, ScrollableTabRow, Scaffold, TopAppbar, BoxWithCosntraints are also easy to Modify. Row/Column is also a little bit challanging at first because they share same code and lots of code to consider like weights, alignments, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, it is rarely needed to actually copy core Composables and make a small change. Most of the time, you will be able to do what you want simply by using the correct containers and/or passing the right Modifiers and content functions.

Having said that, I do agree that it would be nice if those private helper functions were available to use in those rare cases where you actually need a custom copy.